# Use theme-defined settings OR from designer specification?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I have a design specification in PDF from my designer for all screens of my application. He made this specification according to Material Design Guidelines.

In this PDF all screen element sizes are specified. And I have all icon elements used in app in .png files. All of icons are exactly the same as in Material theme.

So the questions are: must I hardcode element sizes from specification or must I take them from correspinding sizes from theme? Must I put .png files from my designer to @drawable/ directory or must I use theme-defined icons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally i save all my dimensions in a `dimen.xml` file and use them throughout my application. This allows for customization and if you ever want to adjust one margin, you can do it in one file and it will be set correctly in your entire application. It also gives you the ability to name your dimensions yourself, wich helps to make your code more readable. Here is a exampe of a dimen.xml file:

```
 <resources>
    <dimen name="action_button_min_width">56dip</dimen>
    <dimen name="indeterminate_progress_size">32dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="logoSize">@android:dimen/app_icon_size</dimen>
</resources>
```

**EDIT**: if you want to use a dimension given by android, but would prefer to give it another name, you can add it to your dimen.xml too, with another name. See the last dimen in the example.

If your designer has send you a document for you to follow, i'm sure he'd want some uniformity throughout the application. That's why google has released a big set of icons to choose from. This way, your app will have a consistent look & feel in all the windows from your app. Click [here](https://www.google.com/design/icons/) to check out the icon set.

Comment: In design specification there are app-specific dimesions and material-design-guildelines dimensions (these which exists already in theme MaterialLight). The question relates specifically to second type of dimesions. I agree that the first type must be specified in dimen.xml.

Comment: The second type i also specify in my dimen.xml because i've experienced some problems using the ones given with the theme ( i used appcompat library on xamarin ).

Comment: what problems did you experience?

Comment: I did not find any dimensions that would create the first 16dip margin, instead all i could find was 8dip. Also i like to give my own name conventions, that way i can really create some order and readability in my app.

Comment: So maybe some trade-off possible: 1) create dimen.xml 2) write there all app dimensions 3) in the dimensions which must be taken from theme make reference to theme

Comment: I didn't thought of that. Sounds like a good solution, i'll apply it myself. I came here to give help, yet i received it instead :p